# Doubt on how to represent the Complement of a set in relation to another

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not sure how to represent a set using a property of the element, well I'm thinking of $3$ ways to represent this, the first way seems to be wrong, because I'm not using the variable $x$ to represent the elements, but I don't know if I can do that, the 2nd method I don't use the variable $x$ for the second condition and the 3rd method, which I think is more appropriate, uses the variable x in both conditions, The first question is, is the 1st form correct? Is there any difference between 2 and 3?

1 shape:

$\complement_B^A = \lbrace A - B\;|\; B \subset A\rbrace$

2 shape:

$\complement_B^A = \lbrace x \in A - B\;|\; B \subset A\rbrace$

3 shape:

$\complement_B^A = \lbrace x \in A - B\;|\; x \in B \subset A\rbrace$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [relative complement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) is the set containing exactly those elements who belong to $B$ but not in $A$ (note this is often denoted by $B \setminus A$.

In this case we are referring to $A \setminus B$ and hence the answer would be all elements which belong to $A$ but not in $B$
$$ \{\ x \in A \mid x \notin B \}\ $$

And note that this does not need any requirement of being a subset you could have them intersect but not be subsets or you could have them disjoint in the latter case, $A \setminus B = A \ \text{and} \ B \setminus A = B$

There is no difference between the second and the third (this follows from the definition of relative complement)